# SQL Query with OPTION clause in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I use SQL Server 2008 as DBMS and I want to query a view with an OPTION clause set to (ROBUST PLAN) in Hibernate.

I tried these solutions :

```
try {
    mylist = (List<MyObject>) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable "+WHERE+" OPTION(ROBUST PLAN)").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

with this error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

and

```
try {
    mylist = (List<MyObject>) session.createQuery("from MyTable " + WHERE + " OPTION(ROBUST PLAN)").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

with this error:

> 2020-06-11 17:14:23 ERROR PARSER:56 - line 1:66: unexpected token: OPTION
>   java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.createQuery(Unknown Source)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.recover(Lantlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet;)V

I don't know how to make this work.

My config : Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
```

Comment: Why cast a Query reference to a list of your object?  Cast, esp. in java, is a bit of a kluge?

Comment: I want to be sure that the list returned match the right class, but even if I remove cast the error is still the same

Comment: You're combining MySQLDialect with MSSQLServerDriver which need to be corrected. Next, I assume you're using MS SQL server and make sure your query runs without any issue. String sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE OPTION(ROBUST PLAN)"; SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql); query.addEntity(MyObject.class); List<MyObject> results = query.list();

Comment: @Govind Yes, I saw on others threads that is a Dialect issue because some data type columns in SQL Server are not recognized by Hibernate, so it only needs to define a custom SQL Server dialect and add missing type column mappings. Btw, thanks for the addEntity it suits better my needs. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad that it helped you, would you mind mark it as  answer & vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're combining MySQLDialect with MSSQLServerDriver which need to be corrected. Next, I assume you're using MS SQL server and make sure your query runs without any issue.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE OPTION(ROBUST PLAN)";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(MyObject.class);
List<MyObject> results = query.list();
```